# Filter picasa query on size

Tags: javascript, picasa

I am using Picasa as an image provider for my website. Now, I would really like to only get the vertical pictures. So pictures that have more height than length. I now this is a big question for google to ask to, but is there a possibility? I think `imgmax` is only used to `GET` a certain size for your pictures.

So my query is: Give me the 10 most recent vertical pictures. I already have this:

```
var q = 'http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/defaultuser?kind=photo&max-results=10&alt=json';
$.getJSON(q, 'callback=?', myFunction);
```

If there is no possibility to do this, I will just get ALL pictures and get 10 verticals out of it. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use their [partial requests](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#PartialResponse) just to pull albumid, photoid, heights and widths of the images and then pull required data depending on your business rules (height > width). This is much more efficient than pulling complete album/photo feeds as google shares a lot of data which obviously takes a lot of time to reach the requesting application.

More info in the experimental section of the [Picasa Developer's Guide](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#PartialResponse).

Comment: I think this will only give me partial metadata, instead of all metadata, but it doesn't filter out the response images that I want.